# Extjs radiogroup with buttons

Tags: extjs

For making a toolbox, I want to know how to make a radiogroup with regular buttons and not radiobuttons in latest `extJS`

Like this with jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

Thanks in advance,
Chielus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should look at using a set standard ExtJS buttons. A *button* can be assigned to a *group* so that they act as the elements shown in your link.

See this example:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Choice 1',
    toggleGroup: 'mygroup'
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Choice 2',
    toggleGroup: 'mygroup'
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Choice 3',
    toggleGroup: 'mygroup'
}
```

Buttons also have a property called `enableToggle`, that allows them to toggle, and is automatically set to true when you set a `toggleGroup`, and `toggleGroup` tells ExtJS how they are related.

Note, they look like regular ExtJS buttons, but behave like you want.

Comment: Thanks, this works. How can i get the selected value now? Besides doing it with an eventHandler for the buttons and a global variable

Comment: If you know which container they resides in, you can go through the buttons and see which one is pressed. If you know one of the buttons, you can find the parent and do like before. I don't know if a `ButtonGroup` will give you any advantages.

Comment: @Chau It works like a charm.. except small issue. There is still ability to choice nothing, means deselect pressed button :(.. Is there any way to avoid such things if some button pressed by default ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a less complicated (better?) way to disallow deselecting a button.  Set the **allowDepress** config option to false:

```
{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    layout: 'hbox',
    defaultType: 'button',
    defaults: {
        enableToggle: true,
        toggleGroup: 'mygroup',
        allowDepress: false,
        items: [
            { text: 'Choice 1'},
            { text: 'Choice 2'},
            { text: 'Choice 3'}
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer @mastak's comment (in the answer above), in order to disallow the action of de-selecting a button, add this listener to each button:

```
listeners: {
   click: function(me, event) {
      // make sure a button cannot be de-selected
      me.toggle(true);
   }
}
```

That way, each click on a button will re-select it.

-DBG

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the @deebugger post. You can also use the following button property to not allow to deselect a selection

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    renderTo     : Ext.getBody(),
    text         : 'Click Me',
    enableToggle : true,
    allowDepress : false
});
```